# Using older version of python with Py-Script

Tags: python, pyscript

Would anybody know how to change the version I use in Py-Script? Currently my Py-Script is using python 3.10, but I would like to be able to use python 3.6.

I had python 3.10 and 3.6 installed, so i tried removing 3.10, but that didn't work, as I also expected, but other than that, I have no clue how to and have had no luck finding any information on the topic online.

I'm quite new to programming, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to go to older version?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot easily change the Python version. Python is included with Pyodide which PyScript loads. Changing the version would require rebuilding Pyodide.

Note: I am not sure if it would be possible to use vanilla Python 3.6 with the current version of Pyodide.

Improve your code to work with Pyodide's bundled version of Python.